# Port 25 works when exe run manually but blocked when run as service

Tags: email, windows-services, smtp, port, executable

I am installing a program for a client which sends outgoing mail only using SMTP on port 25. Normally, the executable file runs as a service, but the initial mail test was failing, so I tried running the program manually (by double clicking the .exe file), which worked (outgoing mail sent successfully).

The service is running as the current user, who is a local admin (we have also tried running as local system account and computer administrator). We have tried with Windows Firewall turned off on the local computer, with the same results. We are coordinating with their tech support to see if they can find out why their mail server is behaving this way, but are not sure if they'll find anything as it seems like an obscure error.

Does anyone know why the port would allow a connection from the executable when run manually, but not when the executable is run as a service under the same user?

This is the error message the service is showing:

```
Error Descrip:  Mail settings could not be validated.  
Details:Connection to SMTP server:  FAILEDTest failed (see details below).
-----------------------------Reason for failure: -> Socket read timeout-> Failed to get initial response-> The SMTP server may be denying access for this domain.-----------------------------
Error details: <?xml version="1.0"  encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?><ChilkatLog><VerifySmtpConnection>    
<info>Checking connectivity to SMTP server mail.<server>.com:25</info>    <smtp_host>mail.<server>.com</smtp_host>    
<smtp_port>25</smtp_port>    
<timeoutMS>10000</timeoutMS>    
<error>Socket read timeout</error>    
<error>Failed to get initial response</error>    
<error>The SMTP server may be denying access for this domain.</error></VerifySmtpConnection></ChilkatLog>
```

This is not my area of expertise. What can I try next?

Comment: Have you ran your service under the Network Service. This should give you the ability to make external TCP/IP connections?

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think to try that before, but we tested that and it still seems to be failing :(. What's more, the Network Service doesn't want to access the local program folder so we're getting file access errors as well.

Comment: I don't think this is your problem, but [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29248544/windows-service-im-writing-cant-talk-on-network-with-windows-firewall-disabled).  You *might* need to enable the firewall but make sure the firewall configuration allows outgoing SMTP connections.  (My research suggests that the Windows Hardening Firewall doesn't work the way that poster says, but I may be mistaken.)

Comment: It would be worth trying a packet capturing tool (Wireshark, WinPCap, etc.) to see what how the connection is failing.  Also check the logs on the mail server, if it is rejecting the connection it should log a reason.